# How would I write a generic function to handle multiple record types in ReScript?

Tags: reason, bucklescript, rescript

Given the following contrived example, is it possible to write a `get` function that can handle any record with an `a` property?

```ml
type type_one = {a: int}
type type_two = {a: int, b: int}

let example_one = {a: 1}
let example_two = {a: 1, b: 2}

let get = record => record.a

Js.log(get(example_one)) // notice the error here
Js.log(get(example_two))
```

[ReScript Playground](https://rescript-lang.org/try?code=C4TwDgpgBKkPoHsB20C8UDeBDAXFAlksAL4BQs0FcwA7glOtnocADRQBGzRZpANhGBQIADywBbMAMQoGmXFACMZAUNESpEanTlMl7LlABMvVVADmguQCcIAYwTWAJgwB8UWw+cA6LKVIAUgDO3nwI5gAUlsAR6pLSyBAAlElQAPRpUEgIwPh2lAAW0BDW1o5QRbaBIWGR0bFi8Vq0CCmkQA)

If not, is this possible with an object? Or, what would be the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: Glenn's answer is comprehensive. IMHO, the 'best way' really depends on your specific circumstances, so really hard to say. If we are talking purely theoretically then using an object type seems to be the obvious solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not. Because records are nominally (as opposed to structurally) typed, there is no way to specify "any record with an `a` field". Therefore `get` will be inferred to have the last type the compiler saw with an `a` field, which is `type_two`.

There is however the object type, which is structural with subtyping, allowing this:

```ml
type type_one = {"a": int}
type type_two = {"a": int, "b": int}

let example_one = {"a": 1}
let example_two = {"a": 1, "b": 2}

let get = (record) => record["a"]


Js.log(get(example_one)) // notice no error here
Js.log(get(example_two))
```

But beware that there are some trade-offs with using objects instead of records, like not being able to destructure them in patterns.

Also, as a side note, another way this can be accomplished in some languages is through ad hoc polymorphism, by explicitly defining a common interface and implementations attached to specific types (called type classes in Haskell, traits in Rust). Rescript, and OCaml, unfortunately does not currently support this either, although there is a proposal for OCaml in the form of modular implicits. You can however still define a common interface and implementations using modules, and pass them *explicitly*:

```ml
type type_one = {a: int}
type type_two = {a: int, b: int}

let example_one = {a: 1}
let example_two = {a: 1, b: 2}

module type S = {
  type t
  let getA: t => int
}

module T1 = {
  type t = type_one
  let getA = (record: t) => record.a
}

module T2 = {
  type t = type_two
  let getA = (record: t) => record.a
}

let get = (type a, module(T: S with type t = a), record: a) => T.getA(record)

Js.log(get(module(T1), example_one)) // notice no error here
Js.log(get(module(T2), example_two))
```

A bit verbose for this use case probably, but this does come in handy sometimes.

Comment: Good answer. One correction: ReScript supports first-class modules.

Comment: Ah, indeed it is @Yawar. It didn't seem to be documented, and I couldn't figure out the syntax for it, but I see now that it is documented under `Advanced->Supported Types`. Answer updated. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Oh right, it's actually documented under genType, probably because it was copied over from Cristiano's original genType docs

Comment: I also missed this section of the docs. This question stemmed out of a JS compat issue. Appreciate the help.